# buscar dato en un archivo json con un search input

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

Como están, tengo la pagina "productos.html" en la que quiero usar un input search para que el usuario busque un producto y los muestre en la misma pagina. Los productos se encuentran en un archivo json, en el archivo "productos.js" puedo tomar el valor del input pero no se como podría recorrer el archivo json para que muestre los productos que coincidan con el valor del input

```
productos.html

<div>
    <input id="searchInput" type="search">
    <button type="button" onclick="searchProduct()" required>Buscar</button>
</div>

<p id="showProduct"></p>

<script src="/js/productos.js">
```

He creado un fetch para obtener la información del archivo json y no se si podria usarse la función filter para buscar el producto

```
productos.js    

function searchProduct() {
  var product = document.getElementById("searchInput").value

  fetch('/js/files.json')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{ 

})

}
```

Ejemplo del archivo json

```
[
{
  "Id": "10AV1000",
  "Marca": "FORD",
  "Tipo": "TIPO",
  "Elemento": "CORREAS TRAPEZOIDALES",
  "Modelo": "COR Ford Taunus Sierra 2.0 2.3",
  "Precio": "778.67",
  "Hora": "21.00;"
},
{
  "Id": "10AV1000",
  "Marca": "PEUGEOT",
  "Tipo": "TIPO",
  "Elemento": "CORREAS TRAPEZOIDALES",
  "Modelo": "COR Peugeot 505 SRI -",
  "Precio": "778.67",
  "Hora": "21.00;"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues con un ciclo `for` lo puedes realizar si no estoy mal. Ya que tu json es un arreglo, podemos obtener la longitud de ese arreglo.
Primero, asigna el resultado de fetch a una variable

```
let myValues = fetch('/js/files.json')
    .then(res=>res.json());
//El ultimo .then() no se para que lo tienes
```

Una ves asignado a una variable y convertido a json para el manejo, podemos interactuar con el

```
for(let i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++){
    console.log(myValues[i]);
    //Ya con esta interacción puedes hacer tu comprobación
    if(product == myValues[i]){
        console.log("Coinciden!");
    }
}
```

---

**SE ME PASÓ DE LARGO**

El ciclo anterior, en la condición te dará error, ya que el objeto `myValue[0]` no puede ser igualado al string de busqueda, tienes que hacer otra interacción para recorrer cada elemento

```
for(let j = 0; j < myValues[i].lenght; j++){
    //Aqui va tu comprobación
    console.log(myValues[i][j]);
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, feliz día!!

---

Resumido

```
for(let i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++){
    console.log(myValues[i]);
    //Ya con esta interacción puedes hacer tu comprobación
    for(let j = 0; j < myValues[i].lenght; j++){
        //Aqui va tu comprobación
        console.log(myValues[i][j]);
        if(product == myValues[i]){
            console.log("Coinciden!");
        }
    }

}
```